# Strange behavior when reading the contents of a register into a C variable

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, linux-kernel, cpu-registers

I am trying to read the contents of a register, specifically `gdtr` into a C variable using gcc inline assembly.  I am adapting some code I found [here](http://fixunix.com/linux/555213-reading-contents-gdt-ldt-user-mode-process.html) in order to do so, but the code is written for a 32-bit processor.  So, in adapting the instructions to 64-bit, I'm encountering some strange behavior that I was hoping someone could explain to me.

Firstly, the `gdtr` struct, which is supposed to model the structure of the gdtr register.

```
struct gdtr64 {
    uint16_t limit;
    uint64_t addr;
};
```

Simple enough.  When I try to output the contents of the register into such a structure via executing:

```
struct gdtr64 gdtr64 = {0xcccc,0xa2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2};
printf("gdtr64 limit: %x\ngdtr64 addr: %llx\n", gdtr64.limit, gdtr64.addr);
printf("<--asm call-->\n");
__asm__ volatile("sgdt %0\n" : :"m"(gdtr64));
printf("gdtr64 limit: %x\ngdtr64 addr: %llx\n", gdtr64.limit, gdtr64.addr);
```

I get:

```
gdtr64 limit: cccc
gdtr64 addr: a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2
<--asm call-->
gdtr64 limit: a0
gdtr64 addr: a2a2a2a2a2a2ffff
```

The values before the call are just junk values so I can tell what's changed.  We can see that the limit was updated from `cccc` to `00a0`, and the last two bytes of `gdtr64.addr` have been changed.  This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

As an experiment, I ran the same code, except I passed `gdtr64.addr` into the assembly section:

```
struct gdtr64 gdtr64 = {0xcccc,0xa2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2};
printf("gdtr64 limit: %x\ngdtr64 addr: %llx\n", gdtr64.limit, gdtr64.addr);
printf("<--asm call-->\n");
__asm__ volatile("sgdt %0\n" : :"m"(gdtr64.addr));
printf("gdtr64 limit: %x\ngdtr64 addr: %llx\n", gdtr64.limit, gdtr64.addr);
```

The output surprised me:

```
gdtr64 limit: cccc
gdtr64 addr: a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2
<--asm call-->
gdtr64 limit: cccc
gdtr64 addr: ff8076db40000097
```

In this case, we begin writing after the memory address occupied by `gdtr64.limit`, but we see that what is written is materially different.  The `00a0` that was the limit in the previous example has migrated to the end of the addr is this one.  Otherwise, we have what looks like the makings of a proper address.

So, I got to wondering if it wasn't something inherent to the `struct` that I was using that was the problem, so I decided to try a string of `char`s.  The register should be 10 bytes long, so:

```
char gdtr_char[10] = "0000000000";
printf("GDTR_CHAR: %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x \n",
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[0],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[1],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[2],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[3],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[4],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[5],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[6],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[7],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[8],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[9]
);
printf("<--asm call-->\n");
__asm__ volatile("sgdt %0\n" : :"m"(gdtr_char[0]));
printf("GDTR_CHAR: %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x \n",
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[0],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[1],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[2],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[3],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[4],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[5],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[6],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[7],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[8],
    (unsigned char) gdtr_char[9]
);
```

Please forgive the verbosity, my C skills are... developing.  The result of this is:

```
GDTR_CHAR: 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 
<--asm call-->
GDTR_CHAR: 97 00 00 50 dd 76 80 ff ff ff
```

Again, the initial values are junk, but we can see that after reading the register, we have all 10 bytes accounted for, but in the reverse order of what we got when attempting our second trial.  To summarize:

```
trial 1 limit: 00a0
trial 1 addr:  ************ffff
-------------------------------
trial 2 limit: ****
trial 2 addr:  ff8076db40000097
-------------------------------
trial 3 array: 97 00 00 40 db 76 80 ff ff ff
reversed:      ff ff ff 80 76 db 40 00 00 97 //byte-wise
```

Incidentally, despite this being broken up into separate "trials", these were run all-at-once.  The contents of the register seems to change between executions (which I also find strange).  Having said all that, I can't wrap my head around the following problems:

- Why do the contents of GDTR change each execution?
- Why is there a difference between using a struct vs. a char array?
- What is the base memory address of GDT (that is, which result is correct [if any])?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=16600&start=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably at least 2 issues you're facing.

The first issue is that compilers add padding for alignment, so what you think is a structure containing "16-bit limit and 64-bit address" is probably "16-bit limit, 48-bits of padding that the CPU isn't expecting and 64-bit address". Most compilers have a (non-standard) extension to pack structures (e.g. "`#pragma pack`" or "`__attribute__((packed)))`" ).

The second issue is endian-ness. 80x86 is little-endian, which means the bytes 0x12, 0x34, 0x45, 0x67 would represent the 32-bit integer 0x67452312.

I'd assume that for the second and third trial the limit was 0x0097 and the address part was 0xFFFFFF8076DB4000. I'm not sure about the first trial though (it looks like the GDTR changed between the first and second trials).

EDIT: Also note that the result for the limit from the first trial looks wrong anyway. The limit is "size of GDT - 1", and because GDT entries are 8 (or 16) bytes each, the limit should always have the lowest 3 bits set (e.g. "0x???7" or "0x???F".

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I put the first trial in there before I realized that the value changed each time.  I will have to edit that.

I had also considered endian-ness as an issue, but don't understand why it wouldn't be consistent between runs two and three, since it's not like the endian-ness would change.

I did check the addresses of `limit` and `addr` at one point, and they seemed to check out, but I will try to pack the struct and report back.

Comment: So the issue was indeed the padding added by the compiler, adding `__attribute__((packed))` to my struct did the trick.  As another experiment, I ran the program 1000 times and found that there were only 4 values that were being cycled through, which seems to indicate that what was happening was I was getting a value dependent on which processor core the code was executing on.